# typo3 extbase: show image (thumbnails) in backend list view

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have an extbase model with an image field, which is just a varchar database field in which the filename is stored:

```
/**
 * image
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $image;
```

If I look at this entity in the backend list view, I can add the image field to the list, but of course it only shows the filename. Is it possible to show a thumbnail instead? How do I do this?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

surprisingly, this was rather easy. All I had to do in my ext_tables.php was add 'thumbnail' => 'image' like this:

```
$TCA['tx_extname_domain_model_entry'] = array(
  'ctrl' => array(
    ....
    'thumbnail' => 'image',
    .... 
  ),
);
```